# Eclipse doesn't recognise Dart SDK or Dartium installations

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, dartium, dart

I'm trying to use the Eclipse plugin with the Dart SDK and Dartium. I installed the SDK, Dartuim and the Dart Editor from `ppa:hachre/dart` through `apt-get` on Ubuntu. The editor works fine, and so does Dartium.

In Eclipse, the Dart section says SDK version 0 is installed at `/opt/eclipse/no-dart-sdk/` and that Dartium is not installed at all. I created symlinks to the directories where they were installed and restarted Eclipse. They are now recognised in the preferences. but my Dart project still says it can't find the SDK. When I try to run the test project. Eclipse throws and error: `Cannot start pub serve or connect to pub`. I ran pub serve through the command line and it worked.

Can anyone tell me hot to fix this Eclipse problem without having to re-install the SDK and Dartium manualy?

Comment: Why don't you use the Dart Editor?

Comment: Because I want to edit the Dart code alongside my Java code. It seems tedious to keep switching between two IDEs and I would have to create a separate folder for the dart code instead of sticking it into Play's file structure. That would mean a lot of copying and pasting to keep re building my project while testing.

Comment: What's your Eclipse version?